# Shiny app closing on all browsers but explorer

Tags: r, internet-explorer, shiny

I am currently working developing a shiny app that process a lot of heavy bayesian models. We are facing the following problem:

Our app suddenly closes if we try to run it in the rstudio browser or google chrome but apparently it is not a code problem since we can run the app on internet explorer, anyone had ever faced such issue?

source code: https://rstudio.cloud/project/413282

If we just run shiny::runApp() it opens a new window with the app, after 3 min (aprox) the new window closes but according to the console it is still running with no errors

Comment: Unfortunately the question in its current form probably isn't a good fit for Stackoverflow. Without knowing the program and the data sources being used, we'd all just be guessing at solutions. If you can pare back the problem to a simple example that only runs on IE but breaks on Chrome/RStudio, that would be of assistance.

Comment: Edited with the example. The problem is that i have no particular error or warning, just a weird response of the emerging window.